# XRay does not show thrown error in the requests, instead it shows 200 OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray

I am using nodejs lambda with the following configuration to show aws traces. I am using @middy as for the middleware. I am using automatic mode for xray so everything is automatically managed by aws.

```
import AWSXRay from "aws-xray-sdk";
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("http"));
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("https"));
```

I have a basic handler with CustomErrorHandling middleware:

```
export const helloWorld = async () => {
  throw new Error("this is just a test"); 
};
export const handler = softOnboarding.use(CustomErrorHandling);
```

This should be shown in XRay traces as a failed call in lambda, but it shows 200 OK.
This custom error handling just modifies the error:

```
export const CustomErrorHandling = {
  onError: (handler, next) => {
   //... some logic here does not matter 
    return handler.callback(null, {
        headers: {Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *},
        statusCode: handler.error.statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(handler.error)
      }
  }
};
```

The thing is that when not using this middleware it works ok (Xray shows 4xx in the node). So I assume I would have to change sth so that Xray catches the error. But how does it know that lambda thrown error. My response is also an error, but tracings shows 200 ok. What do I miss here ?

Answer (score 0):

The root Lambda segment records a 200 response since it was successfully generated and, since that segment is immutable, the status code doesn't change when an error is thrown within the Lambda function. However, you should be able to see the status reflected on the node in the service map. Another option can be to wrap the custom error handling logic in a custom subsegment and record any additional information relevant to your use case as [annotations](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#add-annotations) on that subsegment

More information on the behavior of Lambda facade segments can be found in the [Lambda + X-Ray documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-lambda.html):

"The segment that Lambda creates and sends to X-Ray can't be modified by your function code. You can create subsegments and record annotations and metadata on them, but you can't add annotations and metadata to the parent segment."